# What's the proper i18n ally configuration for a fe/be monorepo?

Tags: vscode-extensions, i18n-ally

I have a project with:

- backend (Express app)

  - locales/
  - src/
  - package.json
- frontend (React app)

  - src/

    - locales
  - package.json

If I open frontend or backend in VSCode (as if they were the root folder, the plugin works as expected), but if I open directly the root folder in VSCode the plugin cannot automatically recognize the config.

What's the proper configuration for this folder structure?